# Error in fstream reference

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
_DLL_EXPORT_
(
bool ,
OpenFile(std::fstream& fileStream )//line 294.17: 

)
{
    char fileName[] = "test.txt";
    fstream fs;      
    fs.open( fileName, std::fstream::out);
    fileStream = fs;
    return true;        

}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

> line 294.17: 1540-1118 (S) The declaration of "`fs`" uses the undefined class "`std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >`" when the class must be complete.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you `#include <fstream>`? Once you fix the compilation error and test your function, you'll probably realize it's completely broken. You're binding a function local temporary (`fs`) to the argument. Think about what happens to `fs` when the function returns.

Comment: yes i have includes that.

Comment: Then please post a complete example that reproduces the error. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

From my recollection, the .open method wants a C-style string as the argument.

Try something like this snippet:

```
    const string   INP_FILE = "InputFile.txt"; 


       ifstream scores_in;
      scores_in.open(INP_FILE.c_str());
```